# ASP.Net WebApi Rest Service - using Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, service

We have an WebApi json rest service written in C# for .Net 4.0 running in AWS.  The service has a /log endpoint which receives logs and forwards the logs onto logstash via tcp for storage.

The /log endpoint uses Task.Factory.StartNew to send the logs to logstash async and returns StatusCode.OK immediately.  This is because we don't want to client to wait for the log to be sent to logstash.

All exceptions are observed and handled, also we don't care if logs are lost because the service is shutdown or recycled from time to time as they are not critical.

At first the flow of logs was very low, probably 20 or 30 per hour during peek time.  However we have recently started sending larger amounts of logs through, can be well over a thousand per hour.  So the question now is that by using Task.Factoring.StartNew are we generating a large number of threads, i.e. 1 per request to the /log endpoint or is this managed somehow by a thread pool?

We use nLog for internal logging but are wondering if we can pass the logs from the /log endpoint to nlog to take advantage of its async batching features and have it send the logs to logstash? We have a custom target that will send logs to a tcp port.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Task in .NET does not equal one thread. It's safe to create as many as you need (almost). .NET will manage how many threads are created. .NET will not start more tasks than the hardware can handle.